# yii2 SiteController метод actions. Зачем нужен этот метод?

Tags: php, yii2

В **yii2** в **SiteController** есть метод `actions`. Выглядит он так:

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Не могу понять зачем он нужен? Заодно подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь хорошие скринкасты, чтобы можно было быстро въехать в **yii2**.

Comment: Но ведь можно просто доки почитать всякие https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-controllers#standalone-actions  ?

Comment: В данном случае переопределяются экшны error и captcha и прописано какие конкретно обработчики должны срабатывать на эти методы

Answer (score 0):

Это Standalone Actions. Почитать что это [можно здесь](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#standalone-actions). Также прочитай обязательно про [Controller Lifecycle](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-lifecycle).

У меня есть пример использования таких actions на учебном проекте.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

class StandaloneController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    // public $defaultAction = 'hello-world';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->defaultAction = 'hello-world';
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'index' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',
                'viewPrefix' => '',
                'defaultView' => 'index',
            ],
            'hello-world' => 'app\components\actions\HelloWorldAction',
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
                'view' => 'error',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionHelloWorld()
    {
        return 'Hello World 2';
    }

    public function actionTest(array $array, $string)
    {
        var_dump($array, $string);
    }

    public function actionForward()
    {
        return $this->redirect('https://google.com');
    }
}
```

Что почитать по поводу Yii 2: [документацию, НО строго на английском](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en). И рекомендую вступить в [русский Telegram-канал фреймворка](https://t.me/yii2ru).